# Copy relative links to absolute links

Tags: cp, readline, ln

Given a directory `/path/to/files` that contains many relative links along the lines of `foo -> ../other/data/foo`, how do I copy the links in `files/` to be absolute path links on `/mydata/path/`

I thought using

```
ls -s $(readlink /path/to/files/*) /mydata/path/
```

would do it, but it just makes relative paths in the new location that duplicate the relative path in the old location, which means all links are pointing at nothing.

What I need is to end up with:

```
/path/to/files/foo -> ../other/data/foo
/mydata/path/foo -> /path/to/other/data/foo
```

What I actually end up with is

```
/path/to/files/foo -> ../other/data/foo
/mydata/path/foo -> ../other/data/foo # broken link
```

I’ve also trying various permutations of `cp`, though the macOS cp doesn’t have a `-s` flag.

Comment: You need to convert the relative path you get with `readlink` to an absolute path before you use it with `ls -s`. See e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4175264/how-to-retrieve-absolute-path-given-relative).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for `realpath`:

```
ls -s $(realpath /path/to/files/*) /mydata/path/
```

will do what you want.

Comment: it works, mostly, but when there is a link named foo -> ../other/foo and another link foo2 -> ../other/foo the second link fails. Still, on the right path and with some bash massaging I can make this work.

Comment: You should edit your question to include, that link names and file names may be different - from your examples one qould not know

Comment: the question I asked was answered, so I thin it’s ok as it is. dealing with the multiple links was not an issue.